# How do i download things through fabric

Tags: python, linux, fabric

i tried to use the fabric to manage my servers. Than i want something like the following code.

```
def get(url):  
    run('wget url')
```

I want to pass an argument to the wget command than on the remote machine download that thing.
But this seems didn't work.
How can i wget something on the remote machine with python or fabric ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `url` passed:

```
def get(url):  
    run("wget '{}'".format(url))
```

Surround the url with `'` to handle special character (eg. `&`).